# Installing Armory on Ubuntu after installing Bitcoin

Tags: launcher

I installed Bitcoin-qt with Ubuntu 14.04. I then installed Armory using a method I found on the internet. However, I could not find the application. I downloaded it again using another method, and now the application icon appears, but it doesn't open up. Can anyone help me? What should I do?

Comment: "using a method I found on the internet" which method it was?

Comment: https://bitcoinarmory.com/download/building-armory-from-source/

[sudo apt-get install git-core build-essential pyqt4-dev-tools swig libqtcore4 libqt4-dev python-qt4 python-dev python-twisted python-psutil
git clone git://github.com/etotheipi/BitcoinArmory.git
cd BitcoinArmory
make
python ArmoryQt.py]

This seemed to work. I entered a password for the Armory and got the 9 columns of root keys. But the icon did not show up.
Then I following this video 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bmUP26r-Pr4

BitcoinArmory is now on my Ubuntu computer, but I don't know how to launch it.

Comment: @user276292: Please [edit] your question to add information, especially if it contains pre-formatted text listings. That way all the relevant stuff is kept in one place and people don't have to rummage through the comments to find them, which in turn encourages more and better answers.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you have actually *installed* armory. Typically you need to run `sudo make install` to install it. After that, according to the armory docs it sounds like you can just run `armory` to launch it. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Totally a speculation, since OP doesn't tell us what they did and what the (intermediary) result was.

Comment: According to their comment they ran a series of commands including `make` but they did not run `make install`. I confirmed that Armory's makefile includes an `install` target as well prior to replying.

Comment: Oh, I didn't read their attempt at a code listing in the comment, because it seemed to tedious do decipher it. ;-P